# example armadillo program won't compile

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, armadillo

I'm trying to compile some simple programs using armadillo (more specifically, armadillo-7.200.2). For example, the simplest I have is the example given on the armadillo website

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<armadillo>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace arma;

    int main()
   {

   mat A = randu<mat>(4,5);
   mat B = randn<mat>(4,5);

   return 0;
   }
```

And I compile this with

```
   g++ example1.cpp -o example1 -O2 -larmadillo
```

The error message I get (with every attempt) is

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/armadillo:154:0,
                 from example1.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/armadillo_bits/Mat_bones.hpp:759:26: error: no members matching ‘arma::Mat<eT>::operator=’ in ‘class arma::Mat<eT>’
   using Mat<eT>::operator=;
                          ^
/usr/local/include/armadillo_bits/Mat_bones.hpp:760:27: error: no members matching ‘arma::Mat<eT>::operator()’ in ‘class arma::Mat<eT>’
   using Mat<eT>::operator();
                           ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/armadillo:155:0,
                 from example1.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/armadillo_bits/Col_bones.hpp:202:27: error: no members matching ‘arma::Col<eT>::operator()’ in ‘class arma::Col<eT>’
   using Col<eT>::operator();
                           ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/armadillo:156:0,
                 from example1.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/armadillo_bits/Row_bones.hpp:200:27: error: no members matching ‘arma::Row<eT>::operator()’ in ‘class arma::Row<eT>’
   using Row<eT>::operator();
                           ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/armadillo:157:0,
                 from example1.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/armadillo_bits/Cube_bones.hpp:418:27: error: no members matching ‘arma::Cube<eT>::operator=’ in ‘class arma::Cube<eT>’
   using Cube<eT>::operator=;
                           ^
/usr/local/include/armadillo_bits/Cube_bones.hpp:419:28: error: no members matching ‘arma::Cube<eT>::operator()’ in ‘class arma::Cube<eT>’
   using Cube<eT>::operator();
                            ^
```

I could only find one instance of these types of error messages:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=680931

I've tried multiple compile options, including using -I and -L to include the relevant files and libraries and including the recommended flags like -O1, -O2, etc. and I always get this same error. I first installed armadillo by using

```
  brew install armadillo
```

and I have uninstalled it once I couldn't get anywhere and attempted a reinstall using cmake (which I also installed with homebrew) and the exact instructions given in the armadillo README.txt file. The homebrew and cmake installs give the error message above for any program I try to compile that includes armadillo.

The best I can come up with is it's something with the compiler I'm using (or something else isn't updated), which is

```
  g++ (GCC) 4.8.0 20120603
```

Some additional info - I'm using OSX El Capitan 10.11.5.

Any ideas?